# Artifactory exception : There should be 10 default repository layouts

Tags: mysql, docker, artifactory

I am running artifactory and mysql in a docker-compose set up. When I run the command '`docker-compose up` ' I get the following error

```
[art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:94) - Application could not be initialized: There should be 10 default repository layouts.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
```

Here is the configuration file 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6086e870c8763e36b59b

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because you run Artifactory Pro with a config of Artifactory OSS.

Some repository types must have a default layout in Artifactory config. A config of Artifactory OSS only include the defaults for the repository types the OSS version supports.

There are number of ways to fix it, ranging from taking the default config file from vanilla installation to adding the missing layouts manually to the config file (see below the 10 defaults).

```
<repoLayouts>
        <repoLayout>
            <name>maven-2-default</name>
            <artifactPathPattern>[orgPath]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]</artifactPathPattern>
            <distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>true</distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>
            <descriptorPathPattern>[orgPath]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).pom</descriptorPathPattern>
            <folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>SNAPSHOT</folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
            <fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>SNAPSHOT|(?:(?:[0-9]{8}.[0-9]{6})-(?:[0-9]+))</fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
        </repoLayout>
        <repoLayout>
            <name>ivy-default</name>
            <artifactPathPattern>[org]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[type]s/[module](-[classifier])-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).[ext]</artifactPathPattern>
            <distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>true</distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>
            <descriptorPathPattern>[org]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[type]s/ivy-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).xml</descriptorPathPattern>
            <folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>\d{14}</folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
            <fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>\d{14}</fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
        </repoLayout>
        <repoLayout>
            <name>gradle-default</name>
            <artifactPathPattern>[org]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]</artifactPathPattern>
            <distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>true</distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>
            <descriptorPathPattern>[org]/[module]/ivy-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).xml</descriptorPathPattern>
            <folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>\d{14}</folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
            <fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>\d{14}</fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
        </repoLayout>
        <repoLayout>
            <name>maven-1-default</name>
            <artifactPathPattern>[org]/[type]s/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]</artifactPathPattern>
            <distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>true</distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>
            <descriptorPathPattern>[org]/[type]s/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).pom</descriptorPathPattern>
            <folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.+</folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
            <fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.+</fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
        </repoLayout>
        <repoLayout>
            <name>nuget-default</name>
            <artifactPathPattern>[orgPath]/[module]/[module].[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).nupkg</artifactPathPattern>
            <distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>false</distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>
            <folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.*</folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
            <fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.*</fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
        </repoLayout>
        <repoLayout>
            <name>npm-default</name>
            <artifactPathPattern>[orgPath]/[module]/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).tgz</artifactPathPattern>
            <distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>false</distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>
            <folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.*</folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
            <fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.*</fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
        </repoLayout>
        <repoLayout>
            <name>bower-default</name>
            <artifactPathPattern>[orgPath]/[module]/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).[ext]</artifactPathPattern>
            <distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>false</distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>
            <folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.*</folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
            <fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.*</fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
        </repoLayout>
        <repoLayout>
            <name>vcs-default</name>
            <artifactPathPattern>[orgPath]/[module]/[refs&lt;tags|branches&gt;]/[baseRev]/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]</artifactPathPattern>
            <distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>false</distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>
            <folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.*</folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
            <fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}</fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
        </repoLayout>
        <repoLayout>
            <name>sbt-default</name>
            <artifactPathPattern>[org]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion&lt;.+&gt;])/(sbt_[sbtVersion&lt;.+&gt;])/[baseRev]/[type]s/[module](-[classifier]).[ext]</artifactPathPattern>
            <distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>true</distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>
            <descriptorPathPattern>[org]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion&lt;.+&gt;])/(sbt_[sbtVersion&lt;.+&gt;])/[baseRev]/[type]s/ivy.xml</descriptorPathPattern>
            <folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>\d{14}</folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
            <fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>\d{14}</fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
        </repoLayout>
        <repoLayout>
            <name>simple-default</name>
            <artifactPathPattern>[orgPath]/[module]/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).[ext]</artifactPathPattern>
            <distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>false</distinctiveDescriptorPathPattern>
            <folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.*</folderIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
            <fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>.*</fileIntegrationRevisionRegExp>
        </repoLayout>
    </repoLayouts>
```

Comment: accept and upvote, my friend. That means "thank you".